# How can I correctly call and run a PHP file and get a response with Angular 8

Tags: php, angular

I try to execute a simple PHP file and get this `return` or `echo`, it is possible with Angular 8 ?

I well build my Angular project with `ng build` and put it in `Nginx server` with PHP configuration

My PHP file don't have a spell mistake error, and I put it inside the `make-bulletin` inside `asset` folder.

Actually I made a service sending a `POST` request in my PHP file locally
I also try with, `return this.http.post("assets/make-bulletin/test.php"...` but it happen the same thing

My service:

```
public makeBulletin(ville: string, pollution: string, date: string) {
    return this.http.request("POST", "assets/make-bulletin/test.php", {
      params: {
        Ville: ville,
        Pollution: pollution,
        Date: date,
      },
    })
  }
```

My `.ts` for call my service and subscribe:

```
public onSubmit() {
    this.bs.makeBulletin("Lyon", "Atmospherique", "2019-06-01").subscribe(
      resp => {
        // How print PDF to the user after get the PDF ?
      },
      error => {
       // get error
      }
    )
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
  $ville = $_POST["Ville"];
  echo $ville;
  return $ville;
?>
```

I tried to add:
`header("Content-type: text/html")` and `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")`

But I get a `200 OK` so good... but, with a `null` response in my `resp`...

**How can I get/read a answer from my PHP file ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP is server-side and angular is client-side which runs in browser so  calling PHP file from assets folder won't do anything.  you can place the php file in some apache server 
 which is  created locally like using wamp and call then call the url like :`localhost:/some-url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the difference between server-side code and client (in-browser) code.

Your PHP code is intended to be run on a server. It cannot be executed in a web browser.

An Angular application (after being compiled to JavaScript) is run in the user's browser.

So, it makes no sense to embed PHP code in you Angular application, because the browser cannot run it.

Your server-side PHP code and you client-side Angular code need to be two separate applications. That said, they can be deployed side-by-side on the server, with Nginx both fronting your PHP application and serving the Angular application to client's browsers.

Comment: Thanks !, I don't realize, it's true we can't execute PHP in the frontend...

Comment: But I have doubt about something, because we actually can POST data with a `from` in HTML to a PHP file, like this `<form method="post" action="pdf.php">`, some old style but this thing work, I don't know why we can't with Angular...

Answer (score 0):

A little bit too late but, Angular is expecting to get a JSON from PHP, so in your PHP you need to do an "echo json_encode($ville);"

```
public onSubmit() {
this.bs.makeBulletin("Lyon", "Atmospherique", "2019-06-01").subscribe({
   next: (data: any) => {
       console.log(data);
   },
   error: err => console.error(err)
});
```

Now you can do what you want with "data" wich contains anything you echoed from PHP.